# How can I get the Msys2 CLI to recognise the emacs ctrl + h key chord?

Tags: key-bindings, terminal-emacs, commands

OK, I hope this is in the right department because I think although this is a problem with using emacs it may be the console window settings causing the problem.

In emacs in most console or GUI desktop windows I can use

`c-h v`

To invoke the `describe-variable` function.

It works for me in a cygwin console window. It works in WSL2 Linux distros both for console and GUI windows. It even works for me in Msys2 with a GUI window.

When I try to use `c-h v` in Msys2 after starting emacs in a console window using the `emacs -nw` switches - just as I do when I start it in a console with cygwin or WSL2 - then `c-h v` doesn't work. It tells me "`v is undefined`".

I can still quit emacs from the Msys2 console using `c-x c-v`. This leads me to think the explanation is probably that the console window captures `c-h` and doesn't pass it on to the emacs app.

The trouble for me is I cannot find an appropriate preference in the Msys2 console window options to change this behaviour. My guess may of course be wrong, but it does work fine in any console except Msys2 which is why I think it's something to do with that specific console window.

So how do I start emacs in Msys2 under MS Windows 11 such that the `c-h v` keystroke combination works in a console window having started it with `emacs -nw`?

Answer (score 0):

OK, since posting this question I have some details which, until I have a better answer, I am posting here as a solution.

MSYS2 has more than one `emacs` package.

When I installed emacs for MSYS2 I used the one found here:

https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-emacs

The emacs package above is the one which caused the problem.

There is another emacs package here:

https://packages.msys2.org/base/emacs

After uninstalling the `mingw-w64-x86_64-emacs` package and installing the `emacs` package and restarting the MSYS2 mintty the problem is solved.

I would still like to know why the `mingw-w64` version does not work but, for now, I am prepared to accept the one I have since installed does work.

I won't accept my own answer as a solution. If somebody else posts a fix for the w64 version I will accept that as the solution instead.